# Filter Google search results for keyword, but only if keyword isn't part of pattern

Tags: google-search

How can I search Google for a keyword such that the result will show "*results containing keyword, but not when found next to a given word*".

For example: **I want all results which contain "apple", but only if the match isn't equal to "red apples"**.

The idea is that if a website has a copyright notice in the footer which is something like "© Amazing, inc", I only want to **find pages which contain the keyword "Amazing" everywhere in the page except than in the copyright notice**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minus search operator should do what you want to do:

```
"apple" -"red apples"
```

Comment: yeah, that just works. unfortunately that means my search doesn't seem to yield any useful result :P